# How do I optimally fill multiple arrays with SIMDs vectors?

Tags: .net-core, optimization, vectorization, simd

Basically, I have an array of vectors I want to "split" into multiple arrays with vectors' values, but I'm struggling to find an optimal way to do this since this is for a performance critical scenario.

```cs
Vector256<double>[] input = GetVectors();
double[] X, Y, Z, W;

// how do I fill X, Y, Z, W with their respective values in a performant way?
```

I've already tried Linq and Parallel.For, Linq is slow and allocates, Parallel.For is twice as fast but still allocates and I feel it's not fast enough.

I'm aware of the array allocations, I'm not counting the array allocation but the allocations Linq and Parallel.For brings by themselves, so you can take sizeof(double) * Count from the allocated memory and still see that they still allocate a lot.

With Count = 1000, the array should be 31.25kb in size plus the point and header of the array itself, but linq still allocates ~0.34kb and Parallel.For allocates ~2.33kb, higher count = higher allocations which I kinda want to reduce as much as possible since arrays can be memory pooled, while Linq and Parallel.For can not.

```cs
[Benchmark]
public double[][] Linq()
{
    var result = new double[4][];

    result[0] = _array.Select(x => x.X).ToArray();
    result[1] = _array.Select(x => x.Y).ToArray();
    result[2] = _array.Select(x => x.Z).ToArray();
    result[3] = _array.Select(x => x.W).ToArray();

    return result;
}

[Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
public double[][] ParallelFor()
{
    var result = new double[][] 
    { 
        new double[Count], 
        new double[Count], 
        new double[Count],
        new double[Count]
    };

    Parallel.For(0, Count, i =>
    {
        result[0][i] = _array[i].X;
        result[1][i] = _array[i].Y;
        result[2][i] = _array[i].Z;
        result[3][i] = _array[i].W;
    });

    return result;
}
```

| Method | Count | Mean | Error | StdDev | Ratio | RatioSD | Gen0 | Gen1 | Gen2 | Allocated | Alloc Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Linq | 1000 | 13.259 us | 0.1522 us | 0.1271 us | 1.47 | 0.02 | 10.2997 | - | - | 31.59 KB | 0.94 |
| ParallelFor | 1000 | 8.993 us | 0.0837 us | 0.0699 us | 1.00 | 0.00 | 11.1389 | - | - | 33.58 KB | 1.00 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Linq | 10000 | 136.482 us | 2.7235 us | 3.8179 us | 2.94 | 0.09 | 67.3828 | 33.4473 | - | 312.84 KB | 0.99 |
| ParallelFor | 10000 | 46.989 us | 0.6139 us | 0.5742 us | 1.00 | 0.00 | 75.0732 | 36.0718 | - | 314.83 KB | 1.00 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Linq | 100000 | 1,877.981 us | 18.9144 us | 15.7944 us | 1.92 | 0.11 | 562.5000 | 562.5000 | 562.5000 | 3125.51 KB | 1.00 |
| ParallelFor | 100000 | 992.898 us | 19.7800 us | 50.7037 us | 1.00 | 0.00 | 260.7422 | 256.8359 | 256.8359 | 3130.72 KB | 1.00 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I kinda expect some unsafe tricks with unmanaged memory or something to optimize this, or some SIMD witchcraft.

Comment: Is this [c#]?  You should probably tag the language, not just the runtime environment [.net-core] it runs in.

Comment: If this is performance critical, are you able to edit/re-design `GetVectors()` itself?

Comment: Alternatively, can you rewrite whatever is using `X, Y, Z, W`? (With SIMD avoid doing read-SimpleOperation-write functions if possible)

Comment: @chtz `GetVectors()` is not an actual method, it was just an example. Basically, all the data is retrieved from a Database, but as an AoS, in order to process the data with SIMD I have to convert it to a SoA which is basically what I was struggling with, and yes I have access to the whole source code, I need to perform a HUGE amount of optimizations since it needs to process thousands of vectors per seconds for several hours, and even days.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want performance, and willing to use unsafe code. Try the following AVX version.

```cs
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics;
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86;

static class SplitLanes
{
    public static double[][] splitLanes( Vector256<double>[] source )
    {
        int length = source.Length;
        if( length <= 0 )
            throw new ArgumentException();

        var result = new double[ 4 ][]
        {
            new double[length],
            new double[length],
            new double[length],
            new double[length]
        };

        unsafe
        {
            fixed( Vector256<double>* sourceF = source )
            fixed( double* xf = result[ 0 ] )
            fixed( double* yf = result[ 1 ] )
            fixed( double* zf = result[ 2 ] )
            fixed( double* wf = result[ 3 ] )
            {
                // Copy source pointers
                // For some weird reason, the pointers returned from fixed statement are immutable. 
                Vector256<double>* rsi = sourceF;
                double* x = xf;
                double* y = yf;
                double* z = zf;
                double* w = wf;
                Vector256<double>* rsiEndAligned = rsi + ( length & -4 );
                Vector256<double>* rsiEnd = rsi + length;

                // Handle majority of the data with AVX
                // Each iteration of this loop loads 4 vectors = 16 elements,
                // and stores a full vector into each output pointer
                for( ; rsi < rsiEndAligned; rsi += 4, x += 4, y += 4, z += 4, w += 4 )
                    transpose4x4( rsi, x, y, z, w );

                // Handle the remainder
                // Each iteration of this loop loads 4 elements,
                // and stores a single number into each output pointer
                for( ; rsi < rsiEnd; rsi++, x++, y++, z++, w++ )
                    transpose4x1( rsi, x, y, z, w );
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>Create AVX vector by loading 2 FP64 numbers from 2 pointers each</summary>
    [MethodImpl( MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining )]
    static unsafe Vector256<double> load2( double* a, double* b )
    {
        Vector128<double> low = Vector128.Load( a );
        Vector256<double> result = Vector128.ToVector256Unsafe( low );
        Vector128<double> high = Vector128.Load( b );
        return Avx.InsertVector128( result, high, 1 );
    }

    /// <summary>Load 16 numbers from source pointer, transpose, and store 4 rows</summary>
    [MethodImpl( MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining )]
    static unsafe void transpose4x4( Vector256<double>* source,
        double* x, double* y, double* z, double* w )
    {
        double* rsi = (double*)source;
        // x0, y0, x2, z2
        Vector256<double> a = load2( rsi, rsi + 8 );
        // z0, w0, z2, w2
        Vector256<double> b = load2( rsi + 2, rsi + 10 );
        // x1, y1, x3, y3
        Vector256<double> c = load2( rsi + 4, rsi + 12 );
        // z1, w1, z4, w4 
        Vector256<double> d = load2( rsi + 6, rsi + 14 );

        Vector256<double> v;
        v = Avx.UnpackLow( a, c );
        v.Store( x );
        v = Avx.UnpackHigh( a, c );
        v.Store( y );
        v = Avx.UnpackLow( b, d );
        v.Store( z );
        v = Avx.UnpackHigh( b, d );
        v.Store( w );
    }

    /// <summary>Load 4 numbers from the source pointer, and store 4 lanes</summary>
    [MethodImpl( MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining )]
    static unsafe void transpose4x1( Vector256<double>* source,
        double* x, double* y, double* z, double* w )
    {
        double* rsi = (double*)source;
        Vector128<double> v;
        v = Vector128.Load( rsi );
        Sse2.StoreScalar( x, v );
        Sse2.StoreHigh( y, v );
        v = Vector128.Load( rsi + 2 );
        Sse2.StoreScalar( z, v );
        Sse2.StoreHigh( w, v );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! thanks for the answers, I will be making some benchmarks and share the results, by the way, you can replace fixed pointers with Unsafe.AsPointer(ref MemoryMarshal.GetDataReference(arr)) so you don't get that weird immutable copy

Comment: @JustNrik I think the code with `Unsafe.AsPointer` gonna crash if GC decides to relocate the array while my function is operating on the unsafe pointer. `fixed` statement guarantees GC won’t touch the argument, until the end of the fixed block.

Comment: Yea you're right, I've done the benchmarks and vectorizing the code runs 3 times faster with 1k elements, but with 10k elements it becomes slightly slower and with 100k elements Parallel.For is alsmost twice as faster than vectorizing. Though the memory allocation difference is quite big, 2130bytes vs 56 bytes which for me is great. (I'm already using pooled arrays for proper benchmarking)

Comment: @JustNrik: What CPU are you testing on?  A 100k `double` array is small enough that one can maybe live in the per-core private L2 cache of a separate core for recent Intel, but large enough that it's worth parallelizing.  If threads help, having each thread use SIMD would help even more.  (In C or C++, compilers will auto-vectorizing trivial loops that store a constant value repeatedly, but maybe typical C# compilers don't?  Or wait, you're converting between AoS and SoA, not just filling arrays with constants.)

Comment: @JustNrik: With even larger problem sizes, many desktop CPUs will come close to saturating DRAM bandwidth with just one thread, if that thread doesn't have a worse bottleneck.  Maybe with fast enough DRAM, it might take a couple cores to keep enough memory ops in flight.  Of course, you don't *want* your programs to bottleneck on memory bandwidth, you want them to work in small enough batches of data that it's still in cache between steps of your algorithm, so tuning only for the biggest problem sizes isn't good either.

Comment: @Peter Cordes I'm doing the benchmark on my pc which is i5 6500, but the production code runs on a Xeon (I don't remember the exact model but iirc it was a Xeon Gold 5120)

Here's the bench I'm running https://gist.github.com/JustNrik/36d9e7f0cf6b043cd05775e5df5ce9e6

Comment: @JustNrik Well, parallelization is different story. Try this version, probably faster than `Parallel.For` from the standard library: https://gist.github.com/Const-me/4482127ea797b865b7e2e77fcf429dd5

Comment: @Soonts  bench results https://hatebin.com/qlhiojatqn, faster than Parallel.For in the beginning but becomes twice slower as Count increases, then it catches up again but still a bit slower. Even though, it doesn't allocate much memory as Parallel.For and I guess it will run better with more cores, right?

Comment: @Soonts https://hatebin.com/hajdnnoezw benchmark results from production code, for bigger counts it tends to run faster and has little allocation

Comment: @JustNrik To be honest, I have no idea how to explain your results. Your server CPU does what I expect it would do i.e. faster than `Parallel.For`. However, your i5 does something weird I don’t understand. Maybe your i5 is stalled on these intel’s power license limits for AVX code i.e. it wastes time transitioning between power states. You could try changing `minParallel` and `parallellBatch` magic numbers, also decrease `0x100` constant at the end of `transposeParallel` method to 16.

Comment: @Soonts I'm fine with it, if the server cpu is running as fast as it should, then it's ok, I don't use my pc for processing heavy data anyways, mostly testing and debugging small chunks of sample data and coding